# Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{S}^4$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, covering-spaces

I got confused on a problem to check if $\mathbb{S^4}$ is a covering space $\mathbb{C}\text{P}^2$. I'm trying to compute their cohomology rings and read the homomorphism. But I don't know how does it connect to decide a covering space. Another hint I got is to consider the volume form and De Rham cohomology, but I'm struggling on the details. Can anybody help?

Comment: They are both simply connected.

Comment: How does it may help?

Comment: Is there any non-trivial covering map between simply connected spaces?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thus you have to show that $S^4$ and $\mathbb C P^2$ are not homeomorphic ;-)

Comment: Would you let me know more details on that? Why this reduce to the case to show non-homeomorphism? Meanwhile, I just read the fact that "any simply connected space has no non-trivial covering"...

Comment: To be honest, I find it quite weird that you are supposed to know deRham cohomology and its ring structure, but do not know a simple fact in covering space theory. Can you tell us what is your background?

Comment: @ArcticChar I can see that $p_*: \pi_1(E, e) \rightarrow \pi_1(B, b)$ provided both $E$ and $B$ are simply-connected implies the injectivity and surjectivity of $p$. But how do we know about if it's evenly covered due to the definition? For the non-homeomorphism things: given $p$ is a covering map and $B$ is simply-connected, then $p$ is a homeomorphism, so the contra-positive tells it's not a covering map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that $\mathbb CP^2$ has a CW-structure with one cell in dimensions $0,2,4$. Hence the fundamental group of $\mathbb CP^2$ agrees with the fundamental group of the $2$-skeleton which is a copy of $S^2$. Thus $\mathbb CP^2$  is simply connected.

Since $\mathbb CP^2$ is simply connected, it is its own universal covering space. Universal covering spaces (i.e. simply connected covering spaces) are unique up to isomorphism of covering spaces. Thus if there exists a covering space $p : S^4 \to \mathbb CP^2$, we must have $S^4 \approx \mathbb CP^2$.

The homology groups $H_k(\mathbb CP^2)$ are $\mathbb Z$ for $k = 0,2,4$ and $0$ else. This follows easily by computing the cellular homology groups. See also [Representatives of generators for the homology group of the complex projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3438883). Therefore $S^4 \not\approx \mathbb CP^2$.